# Where do I find googlemaps.MapContainer to import for the Ratatouilles Restaurant demo?

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to run the Ratatouilles Restaurant demo.  Where do I find the googlemaps.MapContainer to import.

Answer (score 1):

This demo uses the [GoogleMaps.cn1lib](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/) that is in the lib directory, to use this right click on your project and select "CodenameOne->Refresh cn1lib files" then rebuild the project